# ReadPipe hangs on Mac OS X 10.11

Tags: macos, cocoa, usb, iokit

I’ve used the code from the Apple examples:

```
// Send data through out pipe
ret = (*usbInterface)->WritePipe(usbInterface, bulkOutRef, (void *)kTestMessage, 4);
if (ret != kIOReturnSuccess)
{
   NSLog(@"Write failed (error: %x)\n", ret);
}
// Read data through in pipe 
numBytes = 64;
inp = malloc(numBytes);
ret = (*usbInterface)->ReadPipe(usbInterface, bulkInRef, inp, &numBytes);
```

The pipe references are checked with `GetPipeProperties` (and doubled checked with USB Prober).
I’ve also tried the asynch version, with the same results: the writes work (it seems to), the reads hang.
I’ve also tried some debugging with `usbtrace`: after launching once and exiting, it now always returns `The trace facility is currently in use`. 
The USB device is a Microchip USB starter kit II.
Any idea?
Thanks,

Michele

Comment: probably not the problem, but what is your 'bulkInRef'?

Comment: It's an Uint 8, the reference to the input Pipe. In my case, the value is 2.

Comment: maybe check if it's an input pipe with:
(*usbInterface)->GetPipeProperties(usbInterface, 1, &directionOut, &number, &transferType, &maxPacketSize, &interval);

(*usbInterface)->GetPipeProperties(usbInterface, 2, &direction2, &number, &transferType, &maxPacketSize, &interval);

if(directionOut != direction2) {

}

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've already checked it that way, see the text of my question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice before

Comment: Are you sure the device is correctly programmed to respond to the read request in question? If not, IOKit will just sit there hanging. It's usually a good idea to use the read and write pipe method variants that allow specifying a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had to send a request to the device using `WritePipe` on the OUT pipe and then read the response using `ReadPipe` at the IN pipe. I didn't get it, it was my fault.